# Data won't show in Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data on my To-Do app will not show up in the Firestore Database. I get a warning in the terminal that reads "WARNING in src/components/AddTodo.js  Line 3:10:  'collection' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars"

In the console it also reads Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.db.collection is not a function.

AddToDo.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

export default function AddTodo() {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title !== '') {
      await addDoc(db.collection('todos'), {  //<----Problem???--->//
        title,
        completed: false,
      });
      setTitle('');
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input_container">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter todo..."
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="btn_container">
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Title from './components/Title';
import AddTodo from './components/AddTodo';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Title />
      </div>
      <div>
        <AddTodo />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

//Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCqranC2Lg9HXqoPPVAB3BVQqJFMAi569E',
  authDomain: 'fir-todo-ee3df.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'fir-todo-ee3df',
  storageBucket: 'fir-todo-ee3df.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '861076554800',
  appId: '1:861076554800:web:070895ff68a12d187f99f5',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };
```

Title.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Title() {
  return (
    <div className="title">
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own answer. This was a matter of syntax since Firebase updated to the latest SDK version. Line 11 should read as
*await addDoc(collection(db, 'todos'), {*

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using v9 (modular) of firebase.

Try using this code:

```
await addDoc(collection(db, 'todos'), { 
        title,
        completed: false,
      });
```

You can check the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8_6) for more information on how to add new documents.

Comment: Way to go @chaz-carothers. I posted my answer 2 minutes late, anyway I hope you found my answer helpful. Keep up the good work!